# Shared folder of VirtualBox as Apache2 www directory

Tags: linux, virtualbox, apache-http-server, shared-folders

I using VirtualBox in Windows and I have installed Kali Linux on it. I have configured NAT network so that I can connect to the Apache server in the Linux VM through Windows browser. It works fine and I can access files in `/var/www` folder in my VM.

I have set a shared folder that can be accessed by both Windows and Kali Linux. I want to set that folder as the `www` folder Apache2 server. How can I do that..?

I tried editing `apache2.conf` file by replacing `<Directory /var/www>` as `<Directory /media/sf_www>`. (`sf_www` is the shared folder). But it gives `403` error.

Then I tried replacing `vboxsf:x:142:` with `vboxsf:x:142:www-data` in `/etc/group` file and restart the VM. But the result was same.

So, how can I configure a shared folder as the `www` folder of the Apache2 server..?

Comment: how do you connect the share folder - do you have a system service, use fstab or do it manually with mount command?

Comment: Problem was with the code inside the `<Directory>` tag. Problem solved when I changed it. I did the configuration by referring a Ubuntu tutorial and some of the things in that was not valid for Kali..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to manually mount the folder. Tick the `auto mount` option in the shared folder settings. My shared folder is named as `www`. So the folder will be created in as `media/sf_www` in the VM.

Replace `<Directory /var/www> ... </Directory>` tag with the following code in the `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` file.

```
<Directory /media/sf_www>
    Options Indexes
    AllowOverride None
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Replace `DocumentRoot /var/www/html` line in the file `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` with `DocumentRoot /media/sf_www`

Add user group in the file `/ect/group`.

Restart the machine. All done.

Tested in Kali Linux 2016.